Automount does not work after upgrade to 24.04 LTS
I just yesterday upgraded to 24.04.1 LTS from 22.04 LTS
The issue I have is that it does not automount network drives anymore. Manual mount works fine.
In my /etc/fstab I have records like:
10.0.0.12:/Documents  /mnt/Documents  nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
10.0.0.12:/Pictures   /mnt/Pictures   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0

And these mounts are not mounted after reboot, but mount /mnt/Documents works as expected.
Where to look? How to fix?

The reason that the mount at boot-time fails, is that the kernel tries to mount the network-share before the network is ready.
To avoid this, you need to add a _netdevto the option part of the /etc/fstab line. Like:
10.0.0.12:/Documents  /mnt/Documents  nfs auto,_netdev,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0

`
